# Local volatility parametrization using the spot

Tags: options, option-pricing, local-volatility, modelling, parameter-estimation

Is it possible  to estimate the local volatility using the spot price S at time t instead of the strike price K and the expiry date T ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One does not estimate the local volatility at a given $T$ and $K$. Instead, 
Dupire's formula actually gives $\sigma(T,K)$ ***for all*** $T$ and $K$.
$$
\sigma^2(t_0,S_0;T,K)= \frac{\frac{\partial C}{\partial T} + (r - q)K \frac{\partial C}{\partial K} + qC}{\frac{1}{2} K^2 \frac{\partial^2C}{\partial K^2}}
$$
where $C(t_0,S_0;T,K)$ are the call prices for maturity $T$ and strike $K$.
You can also express this directly in terms of the whole implied volatility surface $\Sigma : (T,K) \mapsto \Sigma(T,K)$.

Once you computed the function, you can evaluate at $T = t$ and $K = S$ or any other value you want.